# How to display details of SQLite query in a ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android

I have stored the names and friends in database.

For example ,

```
person A,and his friends B,C,D 
person Z,and his friends K,L,M 
person Q,and his friends P,O,N
```

How to retrieve values from database and display in a expandable listview.

i,e.Person A,Z,Q should be the group names and corresponding friends should be the child Name ....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create wrapper for your person

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String[] friends;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String[] getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(String[] friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

}
```

Then put person name to your ParentView
and Friends to a Child in the BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
List<Person>persons; // fill persons

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
persons.get(groupPosition).getName();
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
persons.get(groupPosition).getFriends();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1> Create a bean lets say PersonDetails having attributes nameOfThePerson and array for frnds .

```
public class PersonDetails {

    private String nameOfThePerson;
    private String[] frnds;

    public String nameOfThePerson() {
        return nameOfThePerson;
    }

    public void setName(String nameOfThePerson) {
        this.nameOfThePerson= nameOfThePerson;
    }

    public String[] getFrnds() {
        return frnds;
    }

    public void setFrnds(String[] frnds) {
        this.frnds= frnds;
    }

}
```

2> Get the details from the db using sqlite query and store these beans in arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<PersonDetails> getPersonDetails(Context context) {
        ArrayList<PersonDetails> lPersonDetailList = new ArrayList<PersonDetails>();
        PersonDetails lPersonDetails;
        try {
            dbName = context.openOrCreateDatabase(Constant.databaseName, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM "NAME OF UR TABLE";
            Cursor cursor = dbName.rawQuery(query, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.isFirst()) {
                    do {
                        lPersonDetails= new PersonDetails();
                        /*use gettersetters to feed in details to the lPersonDetails object.*/
                        lPersonDetailList .add(lPersonDetails);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            dbName.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lPersonDetailList ;
    }
```

3> Put it in the expandable list view.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// get the name of the person from the lPersonDetails object in arraylist position wise
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// get the name of the frnds from the lPersonDetails object in arraylist position wise from the string array
}
```